# How to group list of files (strings) by folder and perform select method on the group

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm creating a constant cs file for images in our project.

So I have a list of files like so:

```
var SourceFiles = new List<String>() {
    "Images/BankLogos/ic_card_amex.svg", 
    "Images/BankLogos/ic_nocards.svg",
    "Images/Cars/Toyota_Auris_TS_Estate.png",
    "Images/Icons/ic_current_location_circle.svg",
    "Images/Icons/ic_abn_partially_available_circle.svg",
    "Images/ic_menu.svg",
};
```

I want to use Linq / Lambda.

I figure I must be able to group by slash and then within those group list perform some select methods to output each group section.

This is how the output should look.

```
// Generated code, do not edit.
namespace Common 
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static class Images
        {
            public static class BankLogos
            {
                public static readonly string IcCardAmex = "Images/BankLogos/ic_card_amex.svg";
                public static readonly string IcNocards = "Images/BankLogos/ic_nocards.svg";
            }

            public static class Cars
            {
                public static readonly string ImagesCarsToyotaAurisTsEstate = "Images/Cars/Toyota_Auris_TS_Estate.png";
            }

            public static class Icons
            {
                public static readonly string IcCurrentLocationCircle = "Images/Icons/ic_current_location_circle.svg";
                public static readonly string IcAbnPartiallyAvailableCircle = "Images/Icons/ic_abn_partially_available_circle.svg";
            }

            public static readonly string IcMenu = "Images/ic_menu.svg";
        }
    }
}
```

I have some code to write out the outer section..

```
        private string GenerateCode(IEnumerable<string> files)
        {
            var content = string.Join(
                $"{Environment.NewLine}\t",
                files.Select(GenerateProperty));

            var code = $@"
// Generated code, do not edit.
namespace Common 
{{
    public static class Constants
    {{
        {content}
    }}
}}";
            return code;
        }

        private static string GenerateProperty(string file)
        {
            var ext = GetExt(file);
            var withoutExt = RemoveExt(ext, file);
            var name = LetterOrDigit(withoutExt);

            var v = file.Replace("\\", "\\\\");

            return string.Format(
                "public static readonly string {0} = \"{1}\";",
                name,
                v
            );
        }
```

So I figure if I can group the list used in the select and pass the list in the `GenerateProperty` I could write out each section like `GenerateCode`.

So I think I can manage most of this, but I'm not sure who to group the files / string by the folder and then perform a `select` on that list?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Your `Cars` member appears to have the wrong name.

Comment: Try the key word ```T4``` it can auto execute when you save the file

Comment: @MichaelMao I'm using VS for mac and EnvDTE ism't fully available..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a lot of extension methods, so I built my answer using my existing library of extensions.

First, the extensions:

```
public static class StringExt {
    // return new string consisting only of letter or digit characters from s
    public static string LetterOrDigit(this string s) => s.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).Join();

    // build new string from n copies of s
    public static string Repeat(this string s, int n) => new StringBuilder(s.Length * n).Insert(0, s, n).ToString();

    // return s upto (stopping before) the first occurrence of stopRE
    // or all of s if stopRE is not present
    public static string UpTo(this string s, Regex stopRE) {
        var m = stopRE.Match(s);
        return m.Success ? s.Substring(0, m.Index) : s;
    }

    // return s past the first occurrence of stopRE
    // or all of s if stopRE is not present
    public static string Past(this string s, Regex startRE) {
        var m = startRE.Match(s);
        return m.Success ? s.Substring(m.Index + m.Length) : s;
    }

    // return true if re is present in (matches) s
    public static bool IsMatch(this string s, Regex re) => re.IsMatch(s);
}

public static class IEnumerableExt {
    // return a new string by joining the chars together
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<char> chars) => String.Concat(chars); // faster >= .Net Core 2.1
    // return a new string by combining the elements of s, separated by sep
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> s, string sep) => String.Join(sep, s);
}
```

Next, a slight modification of your `GenerateProperty` method:

```
private static string GenerateProperty(string file) {
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
    var withoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    var name = withoutExt.LetterOrDigit();

    var v = file.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
    return $"public static readonly string {name} = \"{v}\";";
}
```

Next, a new helper method that recursively generates the classes from the paths. The code is somewhat complicated by the fact that I used LINQ so I could use my `Join` method to insert newlines between the sections, so I wouldn't have extra blank lines. In general, you can read `enumerable.Select(v =>` as being the similar to `foreach (var v in enumerable)`.

```
static Regex sepRE = new Regex(@"[/\\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static string GenerateProperties(IEnumerable<string> files, int nestDepth = 1) {
    return Generator(files.Select(f => (full: f, left: f)), nestDepth);

    // internal nested method to convert list of paths to class declarations and member property declarations
    // calls self recursively to handle sub-folders in paths
    string Generator(IEnumerable<(string full, string left)> files, int nestDepth) {
        string tabs = "\t".Repeat(nestDepth + 2);

                  // group tuples of (full path, rest of path after first folder) by first path folder
        var ans = files.GroupBy(n => n.left.UpTo(sepRE), n => (n.full, left: n.left.Past(sepRE)))
                  // foreach (var fg in files.GroupBy...) -- fg is group of paths in a folder
                        // build class declaration from folder
                       .Select(fg => $"{tabs}public static class {fg.Key.LetterOrDigit()}\n{tabs}{{\n" +
                                    // group (separate) sub-paths into paths in further folders and paths in root of this folder/class
                                     fg.GroupBy(n => n.left.IsMatch(sepRE))
                                        // foreach (var sfg in GroupBy...) -- sfg is group of subfolder paths or root paths
                                       .Select(sfg =>
                                            sfg.Key
                                                // if in subfolders, call recursively to create classes for subfolders
                                                ? Generator(sfg, nestDepth + 1) // more nested classes
                                                // if in root, just create properties for each root member path
                                                : sfg.Select(n => tabs+"    "+GenerateProperty(n.full)).Join("\n")
                                       )
                                       // join the sub-folder declarations and root property declarations
                                       // separated by newlines
                                       .Join("\n") +
                                    // end the class declaration
                                     $"\n{tabs}}}\n")
                        // join the class declarations at a level with newlines
                        // (creating a blank line between each class declaration)
                       .Join("\n");

        return ans;
    }
}
```

Finally, a slightly modified version of your `GenerateCode` method to handle nesting and newlines properly, and call the `GenerateProperties` method:

```
private string GenerateCode(IEnumerable<string> files) {
    var content = string.Join(
        $"{Environment.NewLine}\t",
        GenerateProperties(files));

    var code = $@"
// Generated code, do not edit.
namespace Common
{{
    public static class Constants
    {{
{content}    }}
}}";
    return code;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that works perfectly and I'm going to accept it... However, I don't understand the `GenerateProperties`, I thought I understood Linq but it's a lot more complex than I'm use to. Would you be able to put some comments on most lines please? as I say happy to accept regardless.

Comment: Also I've changes tabs to \t and it messes things up... :(

Comment: @Jules I will add some comments. You should be able to replace the four spaces with `"\t"` and it should work fine - I did that initially.

Comment: @Jules I added comments (possibly helpful) and used `"\t"`, and modified the starting `Depth` to be `1` to work with tabs better.